# TFTP breaks when I use ethernet PCI card but it succeeds when I use USB PCI with ethernet dongle

Tags: pci-express, tftp

This question was closed on network exchange and I've been told to ask it here, so:

I have a VM with an ethernet PCI card and a USB PCI card mapped on it.
When I use ethernet PCI card to transfer file by TFTP in 20 chunks of 100MB it breaks down but if I use a USB PCI card with an Ethernet dongle connected to it, TFTP transfers file successfully.
Long story short:
TFTP with PCI ethernet card - doesn't work
TFTP with Ethernet dongle connected to USB PCI card - works

Does anyone have any idea why because I can't find any logical explanation?

Comment: Is your PCI card an extra Ethernet or is it the built in Ethernet.  I don't think an extra PCI card can be passed through to the VM.  Does it all work in the host machine?

Comment: "What" sort of VM platform and how is the passthrough done?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I use KVM platform with PCI card directly assigned to VM. ethernet PCI card is used only for connection from VM to the programmable board. Host PC has its own ethernet card.

Comment: @John It is an extra PCI card. Everything works on the host machine. Only problem that happens is when VM sends file to the board. Like, 50% of the file passes to the board and after that one package doesn't, I get ack timeout and it crashes.

Comment: Is it possible the connection on the board is too slow and does not report back in time to the PCI card?   I am not sure on this but boards attached to my instrumentation computer need their own sofware on the host.

Comment: @John I think as the transfer progresses, so the transfer slows down for some unknown reason